# Can I store FRP outside?

Tags: storage

I have about 7 4x8 sheets of [FRP](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Panolam-4-ft-x-8-ft-White-090-FRP-Wall-Board-H090WTT48096CF/305900400?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&mtc=Shopping-B-F_Brand-G-Multi-NA-Multi-NA-Feed-PLA-NA-NA-Catchall_PLA&cm_mmc=Shopping-B-F_Brand-G-Multi-NA-Multi-NA-Feed-PLA-NA-NA-Catchall_PLA-71700000014585962-58700001236285396-92700010802552466&gclid=CjwKCAiA5IL-BRAzEiwA0lcWYgRBfU87mNOaY0LpH9eDdwpB6ZzFBhUr2lMMdOOp1E-Vcb85qfMNcRoCZp4QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds#product-overview) (fiber reinforced plastic) for a winter project in the house. The FRP is outgassing some obnoxious odor.  It was purchased at a big box store.  The FRP I have is Almond in color, not white as the link.

From the product manual :

> Storage Conditions
> Panels should be stored indoors on a solid, dry, flat surface.
> Do not stand panels on end. Do not stack other materials on
> top of the FRP panels. Do not store panels in high temperature or humidity conditions, or an environment where great swings in temperature or humidity exist. Do not store directly on concrete floors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. It's commonly used in wet and frozen areas, so....

Be aware that it may yellow due to sunlight exposure.  Keep it flat and dry and it'll be fine.

Comment: I'm already violating the storage conditions - i had to move some to the other room and now it is on end.  Outside would be sub-optimal as its a wooded area - high humidity and temperature swings.

Comment: Storing it on end is a bad idea unless it's sandwiched by rigid material. It'll sag and warp severely. High temperature exacerbates this. High moisture in conjunction with freezing temperatures could cause damage. Otherwise, I stand by my answer.